# Error using MySQL to insert data into my DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a script to add a user to a DB in PHP. I want to get the basics down pat before I add in anything fancy. Please note I am new to PHP, I know I shouldn't be using mysql_query and I should be using PDO, but I want to make sure that I have something that works to fall back on.

The error I am getting is this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

My query is as follows:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(`username`,`password`,`email`,`regdate`,`isadmin`) VALUES(
`" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['fusername']) . "`,
`" . md5(sha1($data['fpass'])) . "`,
`" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['femail']) ."`,
`NOW()`,
`1`";
```

(Excuse the password hashing, I'm going to be adding salt later)

I'm executing it as such:

```
$sql = mysql_query($query);

if(!$sql)
{
    die("Account was unsuccessfully created: " . mysql_error());
}
```

I tried adding in $sql to the die(), but it seems to be returning blank.

I've tried removing the backticks, replacing them with single-quotations, having no backticks in the users() function - none of them worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: please post the error you got.

Comment: You only need to quote [identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) with the backtick. Values are quoted with single (or double) quotes. Also, the MySQL extension has been deprecated. You should use PDO or MySQLi instead

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this . hope it will help you.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(username,password,email,regdate,isadmin) VALUES(
'".mysql_real_escape_string($data['fusername'])."',
'".md5(sha1($data['fpass']))."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($data['femail'])."',
'NOW()',
'1'";
```

Comment: Technically, it should **not** be using anything starting with `mysql_*`. Also, you don't quote `NOW()` and you're missing a closing `)`

Comment: I posted this already, but StackOverflow seems to have misplaced my comment.

I don't know if it's possible to mark multiple answers as the best, so I'll post what fixed it here.

1) I removed the backticks and replaced them with single quotes.
2) I removed the quotes around NOW().
3) I added a missing end parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

No need to enclosed the block quotes in values. Check your queries twice or thrice, whenever you getting error. You can try this,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(`username`,`password`,`email`,`regdate`,`isadmin`) 
    VALUES('". mysql_real_escape_string($data['fusername']) . "', '" . md5(sha1($data['fpass'])) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['femail']) ."', NOW(), '1')";
```

Note: mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php